# ProcessBuilder doesnt execute excelcnv.exe correct

Tags: java, excel, cmd

I try to convert a XLSB file to XLXS.
This works in the cmd shell

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excelcnv.exe" -oice C:\Users\myname\Desktop\SoE\sourcefile.xlsb C:\Users\myname\Desktop\SoE\destinationfile.xlsx
```

without problems and it was working in Java before.

```
public void CmdTest() throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd.exe", "/c", "\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\excelcnv.exe\" -oice C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\folder\\sourcefile.xlsb C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\folder\\destinationfile.xlsx");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Dont know what is wrong. The ProcessBuilder is started but the file is not converted.
There is no error message, no output, nothing.

Any ideas ?

Comment: With the full path to the exe file, i don't think you need the extra `"cmd" "/c"`. Can you try
`new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\excelcnv.exe" "-oice" "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\folder\\sourcefile.xlsb" "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\folder\\destinationfile.xlsx")` ?

Comment: I find it always interesting to see that [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is used to run on Windows with the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` to run an executable with using by `cmd.exe` the Windows kernel library function `CreateProcess` and having coding issues due to syntax requirements of `cmd.exe` which would not exist on running the executable directly.

Comment: Please note that `excelcnv.exe` is a Windows __GUI__ application. For that reason redirecting the standard error stream is useless on running this executable directly with `ProcessBuilder` instead of the unnecessary roundabout route of Windows __console__ application `cmd.exe`. `excelcnv.exe` does not output anything to standard output or standard error stream. BTW: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help. It explains how the argument(s) after option `/C` or `/K` are interpreted by `cmd.exe` depending on various criteria.

Comment: Thx @ all
Tigger the code will not work, I also tried to put comma between the parameter and to excape the quotes.

@Mofi thx for your explanation, I was playing around with some parameter and at least I "raised" my knowledge about cmd and exelcnv.

I found Apache Commons Exec but it was also not working. However I was able to find out that my code is not the problem. Google told me that it could be a problem of the classpath length in Eclipse. I exported the program and it is working with my code from the 1st post. Dont know how to fix the eclipse problem but at least it is working.